# Haskell highlighting in E-TextEditor

Tags: haskell, e-texteditor

I have E-TextEditor 2.01. How can I get it to understand *.hs files with Haskell code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the [haskell bundle](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/getting-more-bundles/) from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504/what-are-my-ide-editor-choices-for-haskell/262948#262948) would help?

Or, since I didn't see the haskell bundle there, but [textmate seems to provide a haskell bundle](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles#installing_a_bundle), which you can get from 
http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/Haskell.tmbundle.

The [instructions on installing a bundle with E-Texteditor are on their wiki](http://www.e-texteditor.com/wiki/index.php/Bundles#Installing_the_bundles), which also indicates that the textmate bundles can be used with E-Texteditor.